# What is wrong with my python/pygame program?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to python and pygame and I'm trying to make a basic RPG. When I run my code, it doesn't say anything is wrong but nothing shows up other than a blank black screen. What is wrong with my code?

```
import pygame, sys,os
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

img_path = os.path.join("C:\Users\Billy\Documents\programming\rpg" , "down.png")
img_path2 = os.path.join("C:\Users\Billy\Documents\programming\rpg" , "roof.png")

class player(object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.image_s = pygame.image.load(img_path)
        self.image_b = self.image_s.get_rect()
        self.x = 400
        self.y = 300

    def handle_keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 50
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.y += dist
        elif key [pygame.K_UP]:
            self.y -= dist
        if key [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.x += dist
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.x -= dist

    def background (self, window):
        bg = os.path.join("C:\Users\Billy\Documents\programming\rpg" , "bg.png")
        self.image2 = pygame.image.load(bg)
        window.blit(self.image2, (0,0))

    def draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.x, self.y))

    def checkCollision(self, sprite1, sprite2):
        col = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1, sprite2)
        if col == True:
            dist = 0

class house(object):
    def __init__(self, x=700, y=500):
        self.image_s = pygame.image.load(img_path2)
        self.image_b = self.image_s.get_rect()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def rock_draw(self, window):
        window.blit(self.image, (self.x , self.y))





gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameLoop = False

    pygame.display.flip()
sys.exit()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: Well, you never actually do anything with the window other than initialize it, so I don't know what else you would expect to happen...

Comment: This style of question should go in the Code Review site, right?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Where have you created any object ? It's like you have written bunch of functions and never called them ? So they won't show any errors except indentation error, real bugs would be shown after you make instance of your class.

Answer (score 1):

I just sign-up for writing this answer.

> This is your main gameloop:

```
gameLoop = True
while gameLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameLoop = False

    pygame.display.flip()
sys.exit()
pygame.quit()
```

You are not calling any function in there, and you expecting that? It's normal you see a black screen only.Because you are not called any function in your main gameloop. Also use `pygame.display.update()` instead of `pygame.display.flip()`. And don't use `sys.exit`, use `quit()`.

`pygame.display.flip()` is like [**this**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vndinDhSUSE), `pygame.display.update()` is better .

Answer (score 0):

For a game like yours, a class that begins like this:

```
class(object):
```

will need to be called somewhere later in the program. I would advise you to change it into:

```
class(pygame.sprite.Sprite)
```

Usually with ***any*** class, you will need to call it like:

```
class = Class()
```

if you don't, it won't be used or activated at all. This explains why nothing happens. You haven't called your classes yet. Second, you have a black screen because you never fill it with a color. Most people would want white so here is how you fill the screen with color (in your case):

```
window.fill([255, 255, 255])
```

This makes your screen white. You will put this in your `while` loop but before your `for` loop. I hope this helps you!

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that you need to do two backslashes on your file path or else it's going to think that it's an escape character.

For example, instead of

```
    img_path = os.path.join("C:\Users\Billy\Documents\programming\rpg" , "down.png")
```

put

```
    img_path = os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Billy\\Documents\\programming\\rpg" , "down.png")
```

Comment: This is true, but it's not particularly relevant to the problem the OP is having at the moment.